# Resumir código para consumir un api

Tags: java, java-11

estoy aprendiendo a consumir un api la cual esta en la pagina: https://www.breakingbadapi.com/ y en la documentación me indica de como deben ser los atributos tanto en el nombre como en el tipo de dato lo cuales tengo en la siguiente clase donde tiene su set y get:

```
public class CApiusuariovo {

    private int id;
    private String occupation[], appearance[], category[];
    private String name, birthday, img, status, nickname, portrayed;
```

En el método que consume el servicio tiene un arrayconsume declarado ya que en este guardare los valores que me retorna la api con unos datos que son tipo array y recibo en una `List<Map<String, Object>>` lo que me retorna la api que seria lo siguiente.

`[{"char_id":1,"name":"Walter White","birthday":"09-07-1958","occupation":["High School Chemistry Teacher","Meth King Pin"],"img":"https://images.amcnetworks.com/amc.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/cast_bb_700x1000_walter-white-lg.jpg","status":"Presumed dead","nickname":"Heisenberg","appearance":[1,2,3,4,5],"portrayed":"Bryan Cranston","category":"Breaking Bad","better_call_saul_appearance":[]}]`

Como puedo resumir el siguiente código para consumir el api ??
El método que esta consumiendo el api:

```
// ========================== CONSUMIR API PUBLICA CON CLASE VO -> CApiusuariovo

    private static String urlapi = "https://www.breakingbadapi.com/api/characters";
    static CApiusuariovo apius;

    public static CApiusuariovo getUsuarios(String usuario) {

        try {

            List<Map<String, Object>> respuestaapi = rest.getForObject(urlapi + "/" + usuario, List.class);

            for (Map<String, Object> row : respuestaapi) {

                // Asigno valores al array que estan en la lista map

                String arrayconsume[] = { row.get("occupation").toString(), row.get("appearance").toString(),
                        row.get("category").toString() };

                apius = new CApiusuariovo(Integer.parseInt(row.get("char_id").toString()), arrayconsume, arrayconsume,
                        arrayconsume, row.get("name").toString(), row.get("birthday").toString(),
                        row.get("img").toString(), row.get("status").toString(), row.get("nickname").toString(),
                        row.get("portrayed").toString());

            }

            String[] arrayprint = apius.getOccupation();

            System.out.println("el get occupation array  es : " + arrayprint[0]);
            System.out.println("El get appearance array es : " + arrayprint[1]);
            System.out.println("El get category array es : " + arrayprint[2]);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.print("Error aca" + e);
            Logger.getLogger(CConsume.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        }

        return apius;
    }

    // =========================== FIN API PUBLICA
```

Comment: ¿Resumir te refieres a que sean menos líneas?

Comment: @RuslanLópez Si exacto o una mejor forma de hacerlo

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Java usas?

Comment: @RuslanLópez la 11